# Convert categorical column into specific integers

Tags: python, pandas

I have a bunch of dataframes with one categorical column defining Sex (M/F). I want to assign integer 1 to Male and 2 to Female. I have the following code that cat codes them to 0 and 1 instead

```
df4["Sex"] = df4["Sex"].astype('category')
df4.dtypes
df4["Sex_cat"] = df4["Sex"].cat.codes
df4.head()
```

But I need specifically for M to be 1 and F to be 2. Is there a simple way to assign specific integers to categories?

Comment: Based on your explanation, you could just add `1` to `cat.codes`. `df4["Sex_cat"] = df4["Sex"].cat.codes + 1`

Comment: @coldspeed Yup, of course.

Comment: @U9-Forward Sorry, I was in the process of writing an answer.

Comment: @coldspeed Lol, i did more similar to OP's in my answer :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC:

```
df4['Sex'] = df4['Sex'].map({'M':1,'F':2})
```

And now:

```
print(df4)
```

Would be desired result.

Comment: The map solution needs an extension to gracefully handle multiple categories (think `enumerate`) and the `astype('category')` answer is dangerous because you leave the assignment to pandas, the order is usually lexicographical and cannot be controlled.

Comment: @coldspeed Yup, i removed that part

Comment: Much better. That's why I never post a complete answer in the comments, and that's why you should think carefully before lifting one ;-)

Comment: @coldspeed Lol, yup, added another one with `apply`, less efficient tho.

Comment: I would suggest removing it.

Comment: @coldspeed Okay, believe everything you say, pandas guru you are :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you need to impose a specific ordering, you can use `pd.Categorical`:

```
c = pd.Categorical(df["Sex"], categories=['M','F'], ordered=True)
```

This ensures "M" is given the smallest value, "F" the next, and so on. You can then just access `codes` and add 1.

```
df['Sex_cat'] = c.codes + 1
```

It is better to use `pd.Categorical` than `astype('category')` if you want finer control over what categories are assigned what codes.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use lambda with apply:

```
df4['sex'] = df4['sex'].apply(lambda x : 1 if x=='M' else 2)
```